# Why is my npm install having an error?

Tags: npm

When I run `npm install`, I get this error:

> ```
> npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
> npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/mramahy/Desktop/package.json'
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
> npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
> npm ERR! or email it to:
> npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
>
> npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-26-generic
> npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
> npm ERR! cwd /home/mramahy/Desktop
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
>
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
> npm ERR! path /home/mramahy/Desktop/package.json
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! errno 34
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/mramahy/Desktop/npm-debug.log
> npm ERR! not ok code 0
> ```

Why is that so?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what it is that you are trying to do, and what you did to get this error message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you'll find that node 1.3.x ended a long time ago. I did some hunting and found someone with the same or similar issues. They had issues just two days ago or so. Take a peek here:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10007

Specifically at the bottom of the page:

A dependency of yo expects the binary to be called node:

[Link to yo info](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/spawn-sync/blob/6901f4dee9b91fd9e16ccca2fd3026d25a633d66/package.json#L15)

Comment: try to add essential commands/steps in answer , keep links as reference then  ping me with @Ravan , I will come and give upvote =)